# ThreeJS place voxel on grid with selected size

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, voxel

I am using the voxel painter example from the ThreeJS git repo.

I have changed grid size to 5x5.
However doing this means the roll over mesh isn't fixed to the grid and instead goes over 4 half on different grid squares.

Also i need to have possibility to change grid size to 5x10 or 12x5 or 16x24 and other.
Does anyone know how to do this?

**Here is my code:**

```
  var sizeX = 300;
  var sizeY = 300;

  function init() {
    rollOverGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
    rollOverMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xfeb74c, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true } );
    rollOverMesh = new THREE.Mesh( rollOverGeo, rollOverMaterial );
    scene.add( rollOverMesh );
    // cubes
    cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
    cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xfeb74c,  map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "./wall.jpg" ) } );
    // grid
    var size = 125, step = 50;

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    for ( var i = - size; i <= size; i += step ) {

      geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( - size, 0, i ) );
      geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(   size, 0, i ) );

      geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( i, 0, - size ) );
      geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( i, 0,   size ) );

    }

    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.2, transparent: true } );

    var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material, THREE.LinePieces );
    scene.add( line );

    //

    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( sizeX, sizeY );
    geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( - Math.PI / 2 ) );

  }

 function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.set( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1 );
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

    if ( intersects.length > 0) {
      var intersect = intersects[ intersects.length - 1 ];
      rollOverMesh.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
      rollOverMesh.position.divideScalar( 50 ).floor().multiplyScalar( 50 ).addScalar( 25 );
    render();
  }
```

**Codepen:**  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPrxOX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the positioning of the cubes to the appropriate size, edit the below line accordingly

```
ollOverMesh.position.divideScalar( 50 ).floor().multiplyScalar( 50 ).addScalar( 25 );
```

Change these values depending on the sizes that you require.

Comment: Thx for answer, i trying to change this values but, i can't understand which values should be there

Comment: .divideScalar( 50 )// could be 30 ,20 ,96 its up to you I haven't tried your code or the example...im assuming these values would reflect the necessary change needed

Comment: rollOverMesh.position.divideScalar( 25 ).floor().multiplyScalar( 25 ).addScalar( 25 ).divideScalar( 50 ).floor().multiplyScalar( 50 );
rollOverMesh.position.y += 25; 

it's worked for me, when grid size is an odd number (like 5x5, 7x7, 9x9 etc)

Comment: Good to hear you may need to round other numbers off etc for other equations like i said i haven't tested it but im sure now your on the right track